# Directive doesn't handle event

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I must create a directive where I need to handle the "key eventer event". So I do this:

```
@Directive({
    selector: 'p-dropdown',
})
export class AccessibilityDropdownDirective implements OnDestroy {

constructor(private dropdown: Dropdown,
    private elementRef: ElementRef) {
    this.dropdownHtmlElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("here")
    //  this.replaceKeyDownAction();
    // this.subscribeToDropdownShowEvent();
    // this.subscribeToDropdownHideEvent();
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscriptions.unsubscribe();
}

@HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    console.log(event);//here is never called
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        this.dropdown.show();
    }
}
```

The key-down event is never called also if I press "enter". The console.log in `ngonInit` is called. I need to handle this event, anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
@HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    console.log(event);//here is never called
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        this.dropdown.show();
    }
```

Comment: I need to handle in the component not in the window.